# buffer a lon,lat point in meters (approx)

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I need to create a circle around a point (lon,lat) which is approximately X meters in radius.

The point is generated via the equivalent of `geomFromEwkt('SRID=1;POINT(lon lat)')`.

I am aware of postgis' buffer or st_buffer function, however am unsure how to translate the distance (meters) to the "units of the Spatial Reference System of this Geometry".

[doc](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Buffer.html)
"Calculations are in units of the Spatial Reference System of this Geometry"

Comment: i also understand that this might give a slight elipse shape but i just need an approximate shape so i'm not too concerned about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a colleague filled me in on a approx calculation he uses:

```
buffer("location", radius / 110000 * abs(cos(radians(lat))));
```

where location is the point geometry.

Comment: This was also applicable for me when buffering a linestring in that I picked the rough midpoint in latitude to use.

Comment: Beware this is an approximation that will render an profounder ellipsoid going further north! I really recommend one of the other solutions since I got down this road also and made some horrible mistakes!

Answer (score 2):

The elliptical shape will be more and more pronounced the further north you get. If you're on PostGIS 1.5, do geometry(ST_Buffer(GeogFromText('POINT(lon lat)'),100)) to do the buffering in spherical space and get a correct answer regardless of latitude.

Comment: how do i scale the geometry in meters?

Answer (score 2):

[Here is another way of solving this by transforming into a separate coordinate system.](http://www.gistutor.com/postgresqlpostgis/6-advanced-postgresqlpostgis-tutorials/58-postgis-buffer-latlong-and-other-projections-using-meters-units-custom-stbuffermeters-function.html)

Comment: That is a nice one! Also very usable for similar problems.